# NDK - Resetting the path to Application.mk after changing project directory

Tags: android, android-ndk

Not long ago I moved my project to a directory in a different drive, and only today did I get this message when I tried to Rebuild my project:

> Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file:
>   C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\OpenCVTest\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk

That path to `Android.mk` points to the directory I moved the project **from**. How do I change those paths?

EDIT: Before you ask, yes, the `Android.mk` and the `Application.mk` are inside the `src/main/jni` folder in the new directory, so it's not a directory issue.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you're building your app. If you're using `externalNativeBuild`, change its `path` property in your gradle script.

Comment: I am using `externalNativeBuild`, and changing the `path` property inside `ndkBuild` to `"F:/OpenCVTest/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk"` (the new directory) doesn't work either.

Comment: If you changed the `path` to somewhere on `F:` and the error message still says `C:` then something is very wrong. Are you sure you modified the right file and that you did a gradle sync? How about if you remove the `app/.externalNativeBuild` directory and do a full rebuild?

Comment: I modified the `build.gradle` file for the `app` module, and did several gradle syncs. As for the `.externalnativebuild` directory, I didn't know it existed until now.

Comment: Deleting `.externalnativebuild` did the trick. Does that folder contain the cahces for the `externalNativeBuild` process?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know it contains the actual build command that will be used to build your native code, which is generated from the parameters found in your gradle script.

Comment: @Michael  
Great!
This worked for me too.
Deleting .externalnativebuild did the trick.

This should be an answer and accepted as a solution!